# Exclude node_modules from vagrant sync

Tags: node.js, vagrant

I have a vagrant machine with a sync folder

```
 config.vm.synced_folder "./code", "/var/node/project"
```

When I run npm install i get some errors related to windows

My question? Is it possile somehow that the node_modules folder gets created on the vagrant machine but gets not sync back to the windows folder?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [rsync](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/rsync.html) as the sync type, you can do something like

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./code", "/var/node/project", type: "rsync", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"], rsync__exclude: ['.idea/', '.git/', 'node_modules/']
```

Comment: Here i get the problem that it does not auto sync even if I add rsync__auto: true

Comment: what is the problem really ? if you want the files to be in sync from host to VM, you need to run `vagrant rsync-auto` see https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/rsync-auto.html